# Match exactly 12 non-contiguous letters in Regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write some Regex that will match lines with exactly 12 letters (case-insensitive).

For instance, I want it to match 123124ab234cdef234gh1111ijkL (12 letters), but not abcdefgh1111ijk (11 letters) or abcdefgh1111ijkLM (13 letters). My thought was to do a nested lookahead twelve times:

```
(?=(.*[A-Za-z])(?=(.*[A-Za-z])(?=(.*[A-Za-z])(?=(.*[A-Za-z]).....))))
```

But this doesn't work. Neither does a simple twelve-letter match because the letters do not have to be conitguous:

```
[A-Za-z]{12}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you just match `([A-Za-z])` and count the matches? E.g. `Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches("123124ab234cdef234gh1111ijkL", "([A-Za-z])").Count = 12)` works in VB.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
^([^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){12}[^a-zA-Z]*$
```

A quick break down:

```
^              # match the start of the input
(              # start group 1
  [^a-zA-Z]*   #   match zero or more non-letter chars
  [a-zA-Z]     #   match one letter
){12}          # end group 1 and match exactly 12 times
[^a-zA-Z]*     # match zero or more non-letter chars
$              # match the end of the input
```

Note that `[a-zA-Z]` only matches the ASCII letters! The char `'É'` wil not be matched by it. And therefor, `[^a-zA-Z]` *does* match `'É'`.

Comment: @MattThompson If you truly want letters, you can use the Unicode character class \p{L} or its complement \P{L}. See 
[Supported Unicode General Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories). _Why Unicode?_ Because that's what .NET strings are!